# splitting up a gruntfile

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have this task in my gruntfile:

```
jade: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            client: false,
            pretty: true,
             data: {
                  section: grunt.file.readJSON('json/section.json')
             }
        },
        files: [ {
          cwd: "app/views",
          src: "**/*.jade",
          dest: "build/templates",
          expand: true,
          ext: ".html"
        } ]
    }
}
```

However when I add this snippet to a js file **jade.js** like so:

module.exports = {

```
compile: {
    options: {
        client: false,
        pretty: true,
         data: {
              section: grunt.file.readJSON('json/section.json')
         }
    },
    files: [ {
      cwd: "app/views",
      src: "**/*.jade",
      dest: "build/templates",
      expand: true,
      ext: ".html"
    } ]
}
```

}

I get the error **ReferenceError: grunt is not defined**

although I have the following setup:

**aliases.yaml**

```
    default:
      - 'jade'
      - 'sass'
      - 'watch
```

**FOLDER STRUCTURE**

```
/grunt   
    aliases.yaml
    jade.js  
    sass.js  
    watch.js
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // load grunt config
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
};
```

I have load-grunt-config and load-grunt-tasks both installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `grunt` in your config, you have to use the function form for the jade.js file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt, options) {
  return {
    compile: {
      options: {
        client: false,
        pretty: true,
         data: {
              section: grunt.file.readJSON('json/section.json')
         }
      },
      files: [ {
        cwd: "app/views",
        src: "**/*.jade",
        dest: "build/templates",
        expand: true,
        ext: ".html"
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you sir are a true hero! I salute you.